# Homestead installation updating my host machine

Tags: symfony, composer-php, homestead

**Description**

Ok, I want to use a virtual machine with *Vagrant* and *Homestead* on my computer to work on my websites in the same context as their production server. That's the all point of using a virtual host isnt it ? To get rid of dependencies conflicts between your host mahcine and your projects requirements.

**Example**

> The production server of my project A needs PHP5.6, i want my virtual
>   machine to run PHP5.6, while my host machine can run another version
>   of PHP. Am i right ?

Following [Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/homestead.html) and [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead) documentations, I must run "composer require laravel/homestead" into my project folder to install homestead... which leads to install my project dependencies on my host machine !!

Am I missunderstanding virtual machine purpose or what ?

I guess I could put my project folder into a sub directory, so there would be 2 composer.(json|lock) files, but it breaks my git structure

Answer (score 0):

Homestead is *not* the virtual machine, but a CLI tool and Vagrant box to setup a virtual machine for PHP projects easily.

It configures Vagrant for you in such a way that you can create virtual machines for your PHP projects easily, it's not the virtual machine itself.

Install homestead as a global Composer dependency (it's just a CLI application) and use the `homestead` command to configure, start and shutdown the Vagrant virtual machine.

Comment: I followed the chapter "Per Project Installation" as it is exactly what i want to do. I'd like to deliver a single Vagrantfile to my coworkers, but didnt manage to do it

Comment: then use Vagrant and not homestead.

Comment: "Installing Homestead per project may be beneficial if you wish to ship a Vagrantfile with your project, allowing others working on the project to simply vagrant up." I think i'm not irrelevant